# Status bar color is different to UINavigationBar color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7-statusbar

I have a custom UINavigationBar which I am using to remove the gradient of the navbar in iOS 6. Though the color of the status bar is equal to the color of the screen opposed to the color of the bar

Is there a way to make them the same color or at least make the status bar black. My problem is in ios7.

Also if I change the style of the UINavigationBar translucent to NO like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Then the status bar goes completely black with no writing on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your project info plist, change UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance value, if there is no, then add this key.

Comment: what shall i change it to

Comment: @nivritgupta no its not it doesn't make any difference

Comment: try this     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]; in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions